# Javascript/Nodejs setInterval com início programado, estilo cron simples

Tags: javascript, node.js

Para JavaScript e NodeJS, existem *n* bibliotecas que no estilo Cron robustas, a exemplo de [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). Porém elas são *complexas* demais para situações simples, são pesadas para baixar no navegador ou exigem uma dependência adicional em NodeJS, o que as torna inviável em casos mais simples.

**Quero criar uma função que possa:**

- Aceitar o segundo, minuto e hora em que a rotina está pronta para fornecer dados novos.
- Checar que horas são agora no cliente, e agendar o início do `setInterval` para a primeira oportunidade em que o servidor tiver dados novos.
- Definir o intervalo de `setInterval` como exatamente o período entre as atualizações do servidor.
- Rodar em ambiente NodeJS e navegadores modernos e no IE8. *Caso não saiba testar no NodeJS, eu testo para você*.
- Não deve existir qualquer dependência adicional. Sem jQuery ou package de NodeJS.
- O código deve aceitar um parametro de intervalo do tipo *tentar novamente em x segundos*, e passar um callback para função executada de modo que se ela retornar exatamente `false`, tentará esse novamente até retornar `true` ou chegar no horário da próxima execução padrão. Considera que o servidor pode falhar e retornar sempre erro, mas o cliente deve evitar sobrepor tentativas adicionais!

**Exemplo de uso real**

O código abaixo é responsável por sincronizar uma tabela de um banco de dados com o navegador ou task NodeJS executada

```
/**
 * Sincroniza o cliente com dados do banco de dados. Caso os dados sejam
 * diferentes dos que o cliente já possuia antes, passa ao callback true
 * do contrário, se percebeu que o servidor ainda não atualizou os dados
 * retorna false
 *
 * @param   {Function} [cb]  Callback. Opcional
 */
function sincronizar(cb) {
  var conseguiuSincronizar = false;
  // Executa uma rotina de sincronização de dados
  cb && cb(conseguiuSincronizar);
}
```

Porém, o banco de dados só é atualizado uma vez a cada 15 minutos, isto é, nos minutos `0`, `15`, `30`, `45` de hora.

Como salvar em banco de dados pode consumir algum tempo, essa rotina teria que rodar a cada `15min` e alguns segundos de delay, por exemplo, a cada `15min5s`.

O problema ao usar `setInterval` é que colocar para atualizar a cada 15min, corre o risco de quando o navegador ou a tarefa NodeJS é inicializada, haja um delay entre o tempo em que cliente poderia obter uma informação nova e o tempo em que ela está disponível. Definir `setInterval` em um período menor que 15min causaria perda de dados.

**Bootstrap**

Segue abaixo um bootstrap de como poderia ser feito o exemplo mais simples.

```
function cron (cb, s, m, h) {
    var start = 0, interval = 0;

    /* Logica para calculo de start e interval aqui */ 

    setTimeout(function () {
        setInterval(cb, interval);
    }, start);
}
```

Comment: Você quer uma função que faça `setInterval(func, 5*um_minuto)`, só que sincronizado com o relógio? As 12:30, depois 12:45, é isso?

Comment: Pense no exemplo: um site de futebol, anuncia de 15 em quinte minutos métricas de jogos ativos, porém esse site cai e seu crawler reinicia com frequência. Como fazer um crawler que pode iniciar a qualquer hora preferir acessar a página nos momentos em que ela tem dados atualizados, sem forçar um setTimeout a cada minuto e correr o risco de ser banido? Existem n exemplos práticos disso, em que um setInterval que leve em consideração a hora é hora é melhor do que obter dados desesperadamente a cada instante.

Comment: Se a atualização é feita a cada 15min a partir de 00h00min do dia, e por setTimeout com 15min de dalay, mas a rotina iniciar as 12h14min, você sempre executaria a função 14min depois da informação estar disponível.

Comment: Assim que o usuário fica online, se passa o horário do servidor pra ele, horário que é pra rodar a primeira atualização e depois o tempo de repetição do processo. Já resolveria. Se o cara estiver offline ele não vai baixar nada mesmo...

Comment: Gabriel, por questão de simplificação, não precisa se preocupar com a questão do servidor passar o horário inicial. Simplifica e pensa mais em o horário estar sincronizado entre a máquina local e o servidor que é acessado. Javascript não precisa resolver todos os problemas

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz E por que você não pode simplesmente descontar o intervalo de atualização dos minutos passados da hora atual para *o primeiro agendamento*? No seu exemplo, 15 - 14 = 1, a primeira execução seria agendada para daqui a 1 minuto, e se manteria o intervalo das demais em 15 minutos.

Comment: @LuizVieira **é exatamente isso**. Estou gratificando em 50 pontos quem fizer pelo menos isso. Se tiver mais respostas, o diferencial seria caso o callback da função agendada retornar false, ele tentar alguns instantes depois. Por simplificação, assumir que o `new Date()` do `javascript` estar sincronizado com o horário desejado.

Comment: Uma coisa que ainda não entendi na sua pergunta: você quer minimizar o intervalo de checagem da hora atual, ou rodar o mais próximo possível das atualizações no servidor? O `setInterval` tende a ir defasando, então com o tempo a tendência é atualizar cada vez mais tarde em relação ao servidor, a menos que você verifique o timestamp constantemente. Ou talvez você esteja buscando um meio termo?

Comment: Só depois eu percebi que considerar calcular o delay entre as etapas não é uma ideia boa e que é melhor dar por padrão, por isso que tende a ser interessante além do horário típico de início, opcionalmente aceitar o intervalo explicito, tipo a base da resposta que eu fiz ali e que precisaria ser melhorada. Creio que o melhor seria só checar horário atual quando inicia a função, ela define quanto tempo falta pra chegar na primeira etapa (aqui assume-se que `new Date()` estará sincronizado) e então passa um valor para `setTimeout` que chamaria `setInterval`, que então chamaria a função.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function cron(callback, startTime, interval, threshold) {
    function callbackWithTimeout() {
        var timeout = interval === undefined ? null : setTimeout(callbackWithTimeout, interval);
        callback(timeout);
    }
    if (startTime === undefined) {
        // Corre em intervalos a partir do próximo ciclo de eventos
        return setTimeout(callbackWithTimeout, 0);
    }
    // Limitar startTime a hora de um dia
    startTime %= 86400000;
    var currentTime = new Date() % 86400000;
    if (interval === undefined) {
        // Corre uma vez
        // Se startTime é no passado, corre no próximo ciclo de eventos
        // Senão, espera o tempo suficiente
        return setTimeout(callbackWithTimeout, Math.max(0, startTime - currentTime));
    }
    else {
        var firstInterval = (startTime - currentTime) % interval;
        if (firstInterval < 0) firstInterval += interval;
        // Se falta mais do que threshold para a próxima hora,
        // corre no próximo ciclo de eventos, agenda para a próxima hora
        // e depois continua em intervalos
        if (threshold === undefined || firstInterval > threshold) {
            return setTimeout(function () {
                var timeout = setTimeout(callbackWithTimeout, firstInterval);
                callback(timeout);
            }, 0);
        }
        // Senão, começa apenas na próxima hora e continua em intervalos
        return setTimeout(callbackWithTimeout, firstInterval);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
// Começar às 00:05:30 em intervalos de 00:15:00,
// mas não correr já se só faltar 00:00:30
// 
// Portanto, nas seguintes horas:
// 00:05:30 00:20:30 00:35:30 00:50:30
// 01:05:30 01:20:30 01:35:30 01:50:30
// 02:05:30 02:20:30 02:35:30 02:50:30
// 03:05:30 03:20:30 03:35:30 03:50:30
// ...
// 23:05:30 23:20:30 23:35:30 23:50:30
// 
// Se a hora actual é 12:00:00, começa já e depois às 12:05:30
// Se a hora actual é 12:05:00, começa só às 12:05:30
cron(function (timeout) { /* ... */ },
     (( 0*60 +  5)*60 + 30)*1000,
     (( 0*60 + 15)*60 +  0)*1000,
     (( 0*60 +  0)*60 + 30)*1000);

// Uma vez apenas às 12:05:30
cron(function (timeout) { /* ... */ },
     ((12*60 +  5)*60 +  0)*1000);

// Repetidamente em intervalos de 00:15:00
cron(function (timeout) { /* ... */ },
     undefined,
     (( 0*60 + 15)*60 +  0)*1000);
```

A função retorna o valor de `setTimeout` para poder cancelar antes de começar, e a callback recebe o valor do novo `setTimeout` quando há repetição, para poder cancelar a meio.  Por exemplo, para correr 4 vezes:

```
var count = 0;
cron(function (timeout) {
         count++;
         if (count == 4) clearTimeout(timeout);
     },
     (( 0*60 +  5)*60 + 30)*1000,
     (( 0*60 + 15)*60 +  0)*1000,
     (( 0*60 +  0)*60 + 30)*1000);
```

Comment: Que ótima resposta! Até o momento você foi o que chegou mais perto do resultado. Só não dou a bonificação agora porque tenho que testar o caso com intervalo inicial e tempo de repetição. Porém olhando pelo código, já posso adiantar que sua abordagem foi bem interessante e minimalista

Comment: É, mas acho que não está correcta, eu depois corrijo amanhã (tempo de Portugal aqui).

Comment: Sem problema. Vi que é só essa parte que não está ok, mas a forma como abordou é até mais flexível do que eu imaginava. Pouca coisa e sua resposta estará certa.

Comment: Já actualizei, agora corre como esperado, e também retorna o primeiro timeout para poder cancelar antes de começar, passa o timeout seguinte à callback para poder cancelar a meio, e recebe um limiar para não correr já se faltar pouco tempo para a próxima iteração.

Comment: Sua resposta é uma obra de arte, @acelent. Em 25 linhas de código fez algo até mais flexível do que eu imaginava. Não pude testar todas as possibilidades do seu código, e retorno aqui se encontrar algum problema, porém desde já, parabéns. A forma como abordou o problema foi genial!

Answer (score 3):

Um script de cron simples, só fiz algumas correções no código original pra funcionar.

```
/*  Copyright (C) 2009 Elijah Rutschman

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details, available at
    <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
/*

/*
a typical cron entry has either wildcards (*) or an integer:

 .---------------- minute (0 - 59) 
 |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *

*/

var Cron = {
 "jobs" : [],
 "process" : function process() {
  var now = new Date();
  for (var i=0; i<Cron.jobs.length; i++) {
   if ( Cron.jobs[i].minute == "*" || parseInt(Cron.jobs[i].minute) == now.getMinutes() )
    if ( Cron.jobs[i].hour == "*" || parseInt(Cron.jobs[i].hour) == now.getHours() )
     if ( Cron.jobs[i].date == "*" || parseInt(Cron.jobs[i].date) == now.getDate() )
      if ( Cron.jobs[i].month == "*" || (parseInt(Cron.jobs[i].month) - 1) == now.getMonth() )
       if ( Cron.jobs[i].day == "*" || parseInt(Cron.jobs[i].day) == now.getDay() )
        Cron.jobs[i].run();
  }
  now = null;
  return process;
 },
 "id" : 0,
 "start" : function() {
  Cron.stop();
  Cron.id = setInterval(Cron.process(),60000);
 },
 "stop" : function() {
  clearInterval(Cron.id);

 },
 "Job" : function(cronstring, fun) {
  var _Job = this;
  var items = cronstring.match(/^([0-9]+|\*{1})[ \n\t\b]+([0-9]+|\*{1})[ \n\t\b]+([0-9]+|\*{1})[ \n\t\b]+([0-9]+|\*{1})[ \n\t\b]+([0-9]+|\*{1})[ \n\t\b]*$/);
  _Job.minute = items[1];
  _Job.hour = items[2];
  _Job.date = items[3];
  _Job.month = items[4];
  _Job.day = items[5];
  _Job.run = fun;
  Cron.jobs.push(_Job);
  _Job = null;
  items = null;
 }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
// queue up some jobs to run
var j1 = new Cron.Job("* * * * *", function(){alert('cron job 1 just ran')})
var j2 = new Cron.Job("5 * * * *", function(){alert('cron job 2 just ran')})
var j3 = new Cron.Job("15 * * * *", function(){alert('cron job 3 just ran')})
var j4 = new Cron.Job("30 * * * *", function(){alert('cron job 4 just ran')})
Cron.start();

// Cron already running, but we can add more jobs, no problem
var j5 = new Cron.Job("0 * * * *", function(){alert('cron job 5 just ran')})
```

No caso esse script ignora os segundos, até porque se você não vai sincronizar com servidor, provavelmente vai ter diferença de valores, mas seria simples de adicionar. executa a todo minuto a verificação se há algum script na lista do cron para ser executado.

É fácil de adicionar e remover na lista de processos as rotinas a serem executadas. Iniciar e parar o cron como um todo.

Exemplo pra executar a cada 5 minutos:

```
var meusJobs = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i = i + 5) {
    meusJobs.push(new Cron.Job(i + " * * * *", function(){alert('cron job ' + i + ' just ran')}));
}
```

Comment: Pergunto: como executar uma tarefa a cada sem ter que adicionar 30 linhas a mais só para iniciar ele? Não tem como sem reescrever ele completamente. Outro ponto é que a checagem pra implementar segundos embora seja trivial, pode torrar processamento de forma desnecessária e, no caso de um nó em `NodeJS` que está ocupado em um momento específico, poderia implicar em na hora que executar não ser o momento exato e ele ignorar a execução completamente. Essa falha seria pior do que usar o `setInterval` clássico sem delay programado.

Comment: Mas essa ainda sim é uma resposta que mereceu meu +1. Só não é _A resposta_ da forma como está para o problema apresentado. Algo que ela não faz e cron de *nix faz é permitir mais de um horário exato, a exemplo de "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,45,50,55 * * * *" em cron clássico faria a cada 5 minutos. Isso evitaria caso extremo de 30 linhas de instruções apenas para fazer a cada 2 minutos.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz quando `setTimeout` não pode ser executado, ele não é ignorado, mas sim é executado assim que houver processamento disponível, um `setInterval` quando não pode ser executado, fica aguardando tb, mas como é um intervalo, se o processamento levar 3 vezes o intervalo, na hora que liberar ele vai executar 3 vezes seguidas a função.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz no cron do linux vc pode adicionar `*/5` para executar a cada 5 minutos. E nesse código vc pode utilizar um `for` pra fazer o mesmo com 3 linhas. Adicionei um exemplo pra vc :)

Comment: Bem, nesse caso o tratamento de `*/5` ou `*/2` com o `for` deveria ficar dentro da rotina, não fora dela. Também por isso que a pergunta dizia _estilo cron_, e não _exatamente um cron_, como outros códigos que já existem como o `node-cron`

Comment: algorítimo simples, se quiser algo complexo e completo, dai é melhor usar outro mesmo. se encher de features vai ficar complexo. Nada impede de adicionar diferentes parsers ali até suportar todos recursos desejados.

Answer (score 0):

segue uma solução base que resolve parte do exemplo mais simples. Podem tirar como base para responder suas
perguntas. No momento desta postagem ela não foi plenamente testada e só não implementou casos em que o período é 
superior a hora.

**Não tem problema copiarem o código inteiro dessa pergunta**, porém pelo menos melhorem ela.

**Se mais pessoas sugerirem alterações sem criar a própria questão eu vou abrir essa questão como wiki**, mas seria
interessante alguém postar alterações mais significativas como outra pergunta pra poder ganhar o bônus.

```
/**
 * Agendamento de setIntervalo, estilo _cron simples_. Forneça função, e periodo ideal em que ela deveria ser executada
 * que um delay de setTimeout será executado estrategicamente só a partir de um multiplo do tempo ideal, de modo que
 * otimize o tempo de execucução independente da hora quem que for acionada
 * 
 * @param   {Funcion} cb         Callback. Função que será executada
 * @param   {Ingeger} s          Segundo ideal de início
 * @param   {Ingeger} [m]        Minuto ideal de início. Padrão todos os minutos
 * @param   {Ingeger} [h]        Hora ideal de início. Padrão todas as horas.
 * @param   {Ingeger} [interval] Intervalo em milisegundos para ser executada. Padrão diferença entre horários
 * @returns {Ingeger}            Numero, em milisegundos, que a função será executada. Será 
 *                                zero caso esteja no momento exato
 */
function cron (cb, s, m, h, interval) {
    var start = 0, interval = interval || ((s + ((m || 0) * 60) + ((h || 0) * 3600)) * 1000), d = new Date(), tmp;

    tmp = d.getSeconds() - s;
    start = tmp > 0 ? -(tmp - 60) : -tmp;
    console.log(' > start:segundos acumulados ' + start);
    if (m) {
        tmp = m - (d.getMinutes() % m);
        console.log(' > start:minuto (sem ajuste) ' + tmp);
        if (start && tmp === m) {
         tmp -= 1;
        }
        console.log(' > start:minuto (com ajuste) ' + tmp + 'min, eq a '+  tmp * 60 + 's');
        start += tmp > 0 ? tmp * 60 : 0;
    }
    console.log(' > start:segundo+minuto ' + start + 's');

    // @todo implementar hora

    start *= 1000;

    console.log('inicia em a tarefa em ' + start  / 1000 + 's');
    console.log('intervalo será de ' + interval / 1000 + 's');

    setTimeout(function () {
        setInterval(cb, interval);
    }, start);
    return start;
}
```

Exemplo de saída com uso da função atual

```
console.log('Iniciado em ' + (new Date()).toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substr(0, 19));
cron(function () {
    console.log('Executado em ' + (new Date()).toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substr(0, 19));
}, 30, 5, null, 5 * 60 * 1000);

/*
//Saída do console:
Iniciado em 2014-02-11 15:27:36
 > start:segundos acumulados 54
 > start:minuto (sem ajuste) 3
 > start:minuto (com ajuste) 3min, eq a 180s
 > start:segundo+minuto 234s
inicia em a tarefa em 234s
intervalo será de 300s 
234000
Executado em 2014-02-11 15:36:31 // Idealmente deveria ter sido 15:35:30
Executado em 2014-02-11 15:41:31 // Idealmente deveria ter sido 15:40:30
*/
```